# How to remove element in xml according to subelem file with python?

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I have 8000 blocs of 9 `<variable>...</variable>`in a XML, and I try to keep only the 1st of each bloc. But I don't know how to do it. Here an example of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sss version="1.2">
<date>20-August-2019</date>
<time>11:46:02</time>
<origin>Test</origin>
<survey>
    <record ident="A">
        <variable ident="1" type="multiple">
            <name>Test1_1_16</name>
            <label>blablabla</label>
            <position start="1"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="2" type="multiple">
            <name>Test1_2_16</name>
            <label>Qblablabla</label>
            <position start="2"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="3" type="multiple">
            <name>Test1_3_16</name>
            <label>blablabla</label>
            <position start="3"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="4" type="multiple">
            <name>Test1_4_16</name>
            <label>blablabla</label>
            <position start="4"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="5" type="multiple">
            <name>Test1_5_16</name>
            <label>blablabla</label>
            <position start="5"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="6" type="multiple">
            <name>Test1_6_16</name>
            <label>blablalb</label>
            <position start="6"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="7" type="multiple">
            <name>Test1_7_16</name>
            <label>blablalba</label>
            <position start="7"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="8" type="multiple">
            <name>Test1_8_16</name>
            <label>blablala</label>
            <position start="8"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="9" type="multiple">
            <name>Test1_9_16</name>
            <label>blablalba</label>
            <position start="9"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="10" type="multiple">
            <name>Test2_1_16</name>
            <label>blablalba</label>
            <position start="10"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="11" type="multiple">
            <name>Test2_2_16</name>
            <label>blablalbla</label>
            <position start="11"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="12" type="multiple">
            <name>Test2_3_16</name>
            <label>blablalbla</label>
            <position start="12"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="13" type="multiple">
            <name>Test2_4_16</name>
            <label>blablalba</label>
            <position start="12"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="14" type="multiple">
            <name>Test2_5_16</name>
            <label>blablabla</label>
            <position start="14"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="15" type="multiple">
            <name>Test2_6_16</name>
            <label>blablalbal</label>
            <position start="15"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="16" type="multiple">
            <name>Test2_7_16</name>
            <label>balblabla</label>
            <position start="16"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="17" type="multiple">
            <name>Test2_8_16</name>
            <label>blablabla</label>
            <position start="17"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="18" type="multiple">
            <name>Test2_9_16</name>
            <label>blablalbal</label>
            <position start="18"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
    </record>
</survey>
</sss>
```

And I would like to end with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sss version="1.2">
<date>20-August-2019</date>
<time>11:46:02</time>
<origin>Test</origin>
<survey>
    <record ident="A">
        <variable ident="1" type="multiple">
            <name>Test1_16</name>
            <label>blablabla</label>
            <position start="1"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
        <variable ident="10" type="multiple">
            <name>Test2_16</name>
            <label>blablalba</label>
            <position start="10"/>
            <values>
                <value code="1">TEST</value>
            </values>
        </variable>
    </record>
</survey>
</sss>
```

EDIT:
with the following code I am able to identify them but it's removing only the subelement name instead of the entire bloc variable

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse(xml)

for elem in doc.xpath('//variable'):
    for subelem in elem:
        if subelem in doc.xpath('//name'):
            if "_1_" not in subelem.text:
                print subelem.text
                elem.remove(subelem)
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
for parent in doc.xpath('//record'):
for elem in doc.xpath('//variable'):
    for subelem in elem:
        if subelem in doc.xpath('//name'):
            if "_1_" not in subelem.text:
                #print subelem.text
                parent.remove(elem)
```